# Android google analytics integration error

Tags: android, google-analytics-firebase

When i am trying to get tracker in my activity it show error that -this method is undefine  "getactivity()"     in google analytic v4

```
// Get tracker.
    Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication())
            .getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
```

Comment: if your calling this code from activity then remove getActivity()
if your calling it from fragment then keep it

Comment: thx, it works, but it showing error  java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.analys.AnalyticsSampleApp

Comment: use this 
Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp)getApplication())
            .getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

Comment: thanks for answer, i did that , but error is contineu , please check mainfest file below

Answer (score 23):

If you haven't done so already, create a class MyApplication extends Application for your app, and make sure you add it to your manifest as below (the property that matters here is android:name, I've removed the other xml properties for clarity).

```
<application
    android:name="mypackagename.MyApplication"
    ... >
```

Then, in your MyApplication class, create a method getTracker as per Google Analytics v4 documentation https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#tracking-methods

Then, use

```
Tracker t = ((MyApplication) getApplication())
        .getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
```

Comment: please check the mainfest

Comment: great! nothing of that is mentioned in the google analytics developer guide. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this issue a little while back. To solve it I, as mentioned above, removed getActivity() as well as adding .MyApplication to android:name in the manifest. However I needed to add MyApplication before TrackerName as shown below.

```
Tracker t = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getTracker(MyApplication.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
```

Hope this helps