# when setting a google analytics tacker in an activity, method getActivity() is undefined for the type activity

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

I want to set up analytics for my app and it says The method getActivity() is undefined for the type MainScreen. I have setted up the 'MyAplication, and there I'm getting no errors, so this is the mainscreen code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Tracker t = ( (MyApplication) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
                      TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

                  // Set screen name.
                  t.setScreenName("MainScreen");

                  // Send a screen view.
                  t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());



    }
```

Comment: This thread might answer your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24950341/android-google-analytics-integration-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) class doesn't have getActivity() method. If you need to access the activity use `this.` instead (or just call the activity method directly). You probably copied the code from a Fragment example. Fragments are not activities and you need to get access to the activity with [getAcitivty()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()) method